# vsftp specify root directory for anonymous login

Tags: login, ftp, vsftpd

I have installed the latest version of vsftpd on my system. I did enable anonymous login in `/etc/vsftpd.conf`:

```
anonymous_enable=YES
```

And I mapped the root directory to a folder of my choice, in this case:

```
local_root=/var/ftp/
```

However, when I login anonymously I can't see any files that I placed in that directory. Am I missing anything in the configuration? What do I have to change so that the anonymous user can see the files that were placed in the directory?

I already restarted the service but that did not change anything.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out I had to specify `anon_root=/var/ftp`, not `local_root=/var/ftp`.
After making these changes and restarting vsftpd everything works as expected.